# ¿Cómo guardar la ruta de una imagen dependiendo los datos de un formulario en php?

Tags: php

Buen día de nuevo pidiendo ayuda a la comunidad, alguien sabrá como puedo hacerle para que al subir una imagen la ruta que se obtenga sea dependiendo la información de ciertos campos de un formulario y de no existir la carpeta sea creada y almacene la imagen en la carpeta y la ruta en la bd. hasta ahora creo logre el armado de la ruta y la almacena, pero no me crea la carpeta, ni me sube la imagen, si alguien sabe seria de gran ayuda!! dejo mi código para que le den un vistazo.

Dejo la parte donde se llenan las variables con la información del formulario:

```
$nivel= filter_var($_POST['txtnivel']);
$grado= filter_var($_POST['txtgrado']);
$grupo= filter_var($_POST['txtgrupo']);
```

debajo de esto tengo la parte de la subida de la imagen:

```
$extension = '';
$ruta ='images/alumnos/'.$nivel;
        if (!file_exists($ruta)){
            mkdir($ruta, 0777, true);
        }
$ruta = 'images/alumnos/'.$nivel.'/'.$grado;
        if (!file_exists($ruta)){
            mkdir($ruta, 0777, true);
            }
$ruta = 'images/alumnos/'.$nivel.'/'.$grado.'/'.$grupo;
        if (!file_exists($ruta)){
            mkdir($ruta, 0777, true);
            }  
$archivo = $_FILES['txtfoto']['tmp_name'];
$nombre_archivo = $_FILES['txtfoto']['name'];
$info = pathinfo($nombre_archivo);

if ($archivo != ''){

    $extension=$info['extension'];
    if ($extension == "jpg" || $extension== "JPG" || $extension== "PNG" || $extension =="png" || $extension == 'JPEG' || $extension == 'jpeg'){

        move_uploaded_file($archivo,'../images/alumnos/'.$nombre_archivo);
        $ruta = $ruta."/".$nombre_archivo;

    }else{
        header('location:../extend/alerta.php?msj=el formato no es valido&c=us&p=in&t=error');
        exit;
    }
}else {
    $ruta="images/default/sinfoto.png";
}
```

Mi duda es en que parte puedo estar mal para que no me este creando la carpeta y no me suba la imagen, sin embargo en la bd se guarda la ruta.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Información previa

Puedes simplificar la creación de carpetas si usas el tercer parámetro de [mkdir()](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.mkdir.php) para que lo haga de forma recursiva, es decir, si envías `images/nivel/grado/grupo`, va a verificar que exista cada carpeta o la va a crear hasta llegar al final.

Para simplificar, generalmente uso esta función:

```
/**
 * Verificar que directorio existe, de lo contrario, crearlo
 * @param string $dir    Directorio a verificar o crear
 * @return boolean
 */
function dirVerify($dir) {
    if(!is_dir($dir) && mkdir($dir, 0777, true) === false) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

En tu script la puedes integrar fácilmente con:

```
$ruta = "images/alumnos/$nivel/$grado/$grupo";
// Verificar que la ruta existe o finalizar el script
if(!dirVerify($ruta)) {
    die('No se puede subir el archivo porque no existe la ruta destino');
}
```

### Diagnóstico y posible solución

Ahora, creo que tu problema se debe a que no estás especificando la ruta correcta, tal vez estás en otro nivel y requieras agregar `../` al inicio para subir un nivel, aunque pueden ser más niveles, es difícil saberlo sin ver la estructura de tu sitio y dónde estás ejecutando el script que sube el archivo.

Lo mejor que puedes hacer es crear una constante para definir las rutas de tu sitio, ya sea en disco o por URL, por ejemplo, supongamos que tienes tu archivo de conexión a base de datos en el directorio raíz del sitio y, como siempre necesitas incluirlo, ahí puedes definir la constante, con el valor obtenido de [`__DIR__`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/language.constants.predefined.php):

```
<?php
define('BASE_DIR', __DIR__);
// Abajo el código necesario para conectar a base de datos
```

Si estás usando XAMPP en Windows, `BASE_DIR` quedará con un valor similar a `C:\xampp\htdocs\proyecto`. **Nota:** Prefiero eliminar la unidad y remplazar las diagonales invertidas por normales, pero no debe afectar el funcionamiento.

Cuando quieras acceder a una carpeta o archivo, agrega la constante al inicio de la ruta:

```
// Establecer ruta de la imagen, que se usará también para guardar en base de datos
$ruta = "images/alumnos/$nivel/$grado/$grupo";
// Usas la constante solo para verificar que existe la carpeta
if(!dirVerify(BASE_DIR . "/$ruta")) {
    die('No se puede subir el archivo porque no existe la ruta destino');
}
```

Recuerda que siempre vas a necesitar esa constante para acceder a las carpetas o archivos, por ejemplo, más adelante debes usarla para mover el archivo:

```
// Espeficar la ruta completa del archivo final
move_uploaded_file($archivo, BASE_DIR . "/$ruta/$nombre_archivo");
// Como estás usando $ruta para guardar en base de datos, actualiza:
$ruta .= "/$nombre_archivo";
```

Comment: Nuevamente muchas gracias amigo me funciono de esa manera! una pregunta mas sabrás la forma de como cambiarle el nombre a una imagen cuando la subes, es decir que la imagen a subir se llama cvcvc.png, y al querer guardarla se cambie el nombre por el de algún campo del formulario que sea por ejemplo 1212334.png y se guarde la ruta con el nuevo nombre

Comment: @GustavoCuevasPalafox, necesitas ver la extensión que tiene el archivo y crear el nuevo nombre.